# Store LogCat from Eclipse

Tags: android, logcat

I like to facilitate my developer's live and like to add a command to the External Tools Configuration to store the Logcat automatically.

For this I have a dos-command which works fine in a dos shell :

```
C://eclipse//android-sdk-windows//platform-tools//adb.exe logcat -d > C:\temp\logcat.txt
```

When running the same in eclipse I get the following Error:

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create C:\temp: Read-only file system
```

Any Ideas howto solve this or probably do you know another way to do the same ?

Comment: Have you launched your CMD prompt in admin ?

Comment: Are you trying to automate the saving of log entries from `LogCat`? If not, then it's a complete waste of time as you can just click the Save button in `LogCat` to save the log entries you want.

Comment: Problem is, that during runtime I am not able to select all rows in logcat. It would be easier to just click a button.